# How to model Texas Instruments UCC28700?

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, spice, feedback, multisim

I'm using Multisim in an attempt to simulate a flyback supply design reference by Texas Instruments that makes use of a voltage controller - the [UCC28700](http://www.ti.com/product/ucc28700). Multisim has no SPICE model natively nor does it exist for download at TI's website.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can model it or at least get a approximate (even if ideal) substitute?

EDIT:

I tried to build more or less the same circuit as in the design reference but instead of using Texas' IC, I am simply PWM'ing the FET's gate. Of course this has the implication of not actually using **feedback** (the IC uses both voltage and current sensing techniques), which was the aspect I actually want to simulate and validate.

Still no progress. Insights, anyone?

Comment: What is the circuit?

Comment: @Andyaka It's pretty much the design reference that that show here: http://www.ti.com/general/docs/datasheetdiagram.tsp?genericPartNumber=UCC28700&diagramId=SLUSB41